# What happens to our characters when 2.1.0 (Diablo 3) goes live?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just learned today that we can copy our characters from the official release to use on the 2.1.0 PTR.  Then I wondered:  if I play my characters on the PTR instead of the current official release (2.0.6), when 2.1.0 is released officially, which version of my character will it use?  Will it use my 2.0.6 character or my PTR 2.1.0 character (or will I have a choice)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the patch goes live, your current 2.0.6 character will be retained with all your current gear, stats, and builds.

The PTR character only lives there. They are used for testing and when the PTR is taken offline so is that instance of your character.